# Проблема с accept

Tags: сокет, c++, linux

Здравствуйте. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в следующей проблеме. В сервере на с++ вызываю функцию accept для создания подключения.

```
int sock = accept(sd, NULL, NULL);
```

А затем пытаюсь вывести на экран значение sock, но на экране пусто. Такое чувство что сервер просто не выходит из acccept.
C чем это может быть связано?

```
struct sockaddr_in local;
local.sin_family = AF_INET;
local.sin_port = htons(1024);
local.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

int sd;

if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
}

if(bind(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&local,sizeof(local))<0) {
    perror("bind");
    exit(2); 
}

listen(sd, 5);

pthread_t tid;
int newS;

while(1) {
    newS = accept(sd, NULL, NULL);
    printf("%d", newS);
}

close(sd);
```

Comment: accept блокирующий, он будет ждать, пока кто нибудь подключится (либо придет сигнал,либо кто то просто нажмет ctrl+c, но это тоже сигнал).

Comment: а подключается кто-нибудь(клиент)? а то это строчка отрабатывает обычно (просто я на плюсах не пишу) после подключения.

Comment: В том то и дело, что дальше, когда сервер запускается, клиент подключается успешно, а на сервере все равно ничего не выводится

Comment: А почему в буфер? На экран все же хотелось бы

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, так все выводит. Поясните пожалуйста, то есть "\n" не просто каретку на следующую строку выводит, а еще и с буфера на экран все вытягивает?

Comment: Ну можно завершить строку (я написал выше), там буферизация на строку, можно fflush вызвать...

Comment: Зависит от вида буферизации. Если буферизация на строку (line buffering), как при выводе на консоль, то да.

Comment: Тему надо было бы «проблемой с чтением учебных материалов по printf()» назвать ☺

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что должно? Соединение установлено, напечатан (в буфер, не на экран) номер сокета, и программа висит на следующем accept'е. Всё в порядке. Добавьте в формат перевод строки `"%d\n"`. Тогда и на экран начепятает.